# What are the rulings regarding a person who can't fast

Tags: sunni, sawm, hanafi

If a person of average health (a person who is a little overweight, doesn't have any major illnesses, and doesn't exercise, and doesn't get proper nutrition) is unable to fast, is there anything specific he must do to make up the fasts?

The reson why this person cannot fast is when he does, he gets extreme stomach cramps, bad headaches making him dizzy making it dangerous for him to drive to work, where even if he makes it to work, the pain in the head and stomach is so bad that he can't think, can't concentrate to pray 5 times a day etc.

This pain disappears totally after about 5 days of eating normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sup>[[Al-Baqarah 184](http://quran.com/2/184)]</sup> [Fasting for] a limited number of days. So whoever among you is ill or on a journey [during them] - then an equal number of days [are to be made up]. And upon those who are able [to fast, but with hardship] - a ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him. But to fast is best for you, if you only knew.

If your problems stem from a temporary illness, then all you need to do is make up your fasts at a later date when you are able to do so.  According to the Hanafi school, these days need not be made up immediately.  It is, however, recommended to do so, and dying while these fasts are not made up (without a valid excuse) is considered sinful.

If, however, your problems stem from a chronic condition (e.g. diabetes) wherein you are unable to fast without severely impacting your own health, an alternative is provided: Feed a poor person for each day you miss, after which you no longer need to fast for those days.

The symptoms expressed may be a result of illness (chronic or acute) or possibly just due to poor eating habits during the month.  Diagnosing such things is (obviously) out of scope of this site, but given that many people can fast the month regularly without such problems it is probably worth seeing a doctor about it.

Comment: If I should create 2 more questions about the following questions, please let me know.  1. What happens if the person who can't fast doesn't have enough money to feed the poor? 2. Is there a predefined amount a meal should cost?  For example, the country I am in has meals which will fill your stomach which are as cheap as $0.90USD all the way upto  $580USD.  Where both the $0.90USD meal and the $580USD meals will fill you up.

Comment: @user3550 those should be posted as a new question, but they're both related enough that they can probably be posted as one question instead of two.

Answer (score -3):

Fasting in Ramadan is a source of Allah washing your sins away. This is a great mercy of Allah  and it need a bit of sacrifice from our end for this great reward. This fasts which are being missed need to be made up at a later date. No excuses.

Comment: When God has given two options to make up for missing a fast, there is no one who has the right to say otherwise.